# Laravel resolving a new namespace - which files to add namespace data

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces

In Laravel 4, in `app/config/app.php`, I find the following line under `providers`:

```
'Illuminate\Workbench\WorkbenchServiceProvider',
```

And that service provider works because I verify the `register()` method is called. I wondered how this maps out namespace-wise.  It appears at least in part that the namespace `Illuminate` is declared here in `/vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php`:

```
'Illuminate' => array($vendorDir . '/laravel/framework/src'),
```

I have created a folder in `/vendor` called

```
/vendor/mycompany
```

And then create a class file called MyClass.php as follows

```
<?php namespace MyCompany;

#MyClass.php
class MyClass{
    ..etc..
}
```

I then add the same line in `/vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php`:

```
'MyCompany' => array($vendorDir . '/mycompany'),
```

And call the following in routes.php:

```
$test = new MyCompany\MyClass;      //line 15
print_r(class_get_methods($test));  //line 16
```

BUT, I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'MyCompany\MyClass' not found in .. line 15
```

How do I solve this and get the namespace `MyCompany` registered and recognized?

Comment: `composer update` or `composer dump-autoload` ??

Comment: End better not call the namespace like the root dir. Better do `'MyCompany' => array($vendorDir . '/mycompany/src'),` like the `Illuminate` example

Comment: Can you explain please what I need to put where before I run composer?  That is what I'm trying to find out.  Ideally, I'd like to know how to do it in the code itself.  But I don't even know at this point how to change, or what file to change, to make the namespace update.

Comment: You have to run `composer dump-autoload` from command line.  Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17186605/how-to-avoid-using-php-composer-dump-autoload-with-laravel-4 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29441950/how-to-use-composer-on-windows

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17186605/how-to-avoid-using-php-composer-dump-autoload-with-laravel-4   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306302/composer-dump-autoload-and-git